# iOS Background download or upload time limit for Enterprise app

Tags: ios7, background-process, nsurlsession

With NSURLSession we can fetch data in background i.e. when app is in suspended mode etc. 
For Enterprise apps (Obviously we don't need Apple's approval process) 
**Is there any time limit for background fetch** as with Non Enterpirse apps which is 10 minutes. 
iOS will not automatically terminate it after some time?

One can set app as Audio and AirPlay mode in Background Modes section under Capabilities. I just want to target iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any limit for enterprise applications. You can break all Apple Review Guidelines.

**UPD:** You can not control interval for background fetch. It is controlled by iOS. But you can use `UIBackgroundTaskIndetifier` and `setKeepAliveTimeout` for example.

Comment: Thats ok but IOS will not terminate it automatically?

Comment: No. iOS can terminate your app only because of memory issue. It does not check what background modes your application uses.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will accept your reply shortly. I have another question if you know about that. :- Can we save data in core data in background mode?

Comment: Yes. We can. Application behaviour is almost the same as in foreground.

Comment: I just check your suggestion regarding setKeepAliveTimeout. It only gives 30 seconds extra. So if download task is bit longer so we are not sure when iOS gonna terminate it? I don't think SetKeepAliveTimeout is the option.

Comment: setKeepAliveTimeout just wakes your application up. For long term background tasks you should use UIBackgroundTaskIndetifier